# Unexpected result from trying to use \ce{} from mhchem package with a command defined by \DTLgetvalue from the datatool package

Tags: datatool, mhchem

I have a CSV file with a list of chemical compounds I would like to have parsed through the `\ce{}` from the `mhchem` which converts them to nice chemical notation. While using the raw string as an argument for `\ce{}` works, when the same string is given as a command, the macro does nothing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.csv}
Molecule
CH4
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\DTLloaddb{foo}{foo.csv}
\DTLgetvalue{\methane}{foo}{1}{1}
\begin{document}

CH4

\methane

\ce{CH4}

\ce{\methane}

\end{document}
```

Yields

[image: Screenshot of result]

So  `\ce{\methane}` is not doing anything (it should be putting `4` as a subscript).

Comment: Untested but try `\expandafter\ce\expandafter{\methane}`

Comment: Tested, Nicolas suggestion seems to work.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer, and welcome to TeX.se!

Comment: You are using mhchem without a version option. Please read your warnings.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that `\ce` requires its argument to be expanded (presumably because `\ce` parses it) so you need to use [`\expandafter`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/docsvlist.shtml#gls:expandafter1) to ensure the argument is in the correct format:

```
\expandafter\ce\expandafter{\methane}
```

**Explanation**

Inside `\ce`, active characters (like `^`, `_` and `{`) have a different meaning. An intuitive meaning, but technically very different from standard LaTeX. Therefore, `\ce` has to parse the unexpanded input.

In this particular case, `\ce` found `\methane`, then it did the chemical formatting. Because it doesn't look chemical, it is just copied over and later expanded to `CH4`.

`\expandafter\ce\expandafter{\methane}` makes sure that `\methane` is expanded to `CH4` before `\ce` takes a look at it.

**Tip**

You can create an own command for that.

```
\newcommand*\myce[1]{\expandafter\ce\expandafter{#1}}
```

So that you could simply write

```
\myce{\methane}
```

Comment: @mhchem Thank you for adding the explanation.